# How to Send a text message from the data input on the text view fields?

Tags: android

I am using android studio. I made an application that allows the user to input data in different activities. The goal of the app is that what the user inputs will somehow be retrieved back to me by text message. I was wondering if there was a way to store the information input on the textfields (perhaps using a variable) and then send the variables to my phone as a text message for me to be able to see what was input on them. I’m not sure if this has been done before but I really need help with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think, this can be achieved by using the backend services. Whatever user inputs will be stored on database or somewhere using the backend services and retrieve that data using the sms service from backend system to the specific number or phone.